# Error in my Image Changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, web

Sorry if this is already asked, but i could not find my exact error. I want the image to change as i mouse over and change back as i mouse off. For some reason i get the alert messages, but the actual images do not change.

This is my J script

```
function altimage(){
                alert("hi");
                document.getelementbyid("header").innerhtml="This is good";
                document.getelementbyid("homeicon").src="homelogoalt.jpg";
            }
            function normimage(){
                alert("bye");
                document.getelementbyid("homeicon").src="Homelogo.jpg";
            }
```

and this is my div that hold the image i would like to change:

```
<div class="search" onmouseenter="altimage()" onmouseout="normimage()" style="width:30px;z-index:4;">
                        <img src="homelogo.jpg" alt="Home" class="menu" style="width:30px;height:30px;" id="homeicon">
                    </div>
```

Comment: ignore the 
                document.getelementbyid("header").innerhtml="This is good";

Comment: That was for error checking

Comment: uppercase : getElementById & innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is case-sensitive so:

- `document.getelementbyid` = `document.getElementById`
- `innerhtml` = `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Make you JS as follows:

```
function altimage(){
            //alert("hi");
            document.getElementById("header").innerHTML="This is good";
            document.getElementById("homeicon").src="homelogoalt.jpg";
        }
        function normimage(){
            //alert("bye");
            document.getElementById("homeicon").src="Homelogo.jpg";
        }
```

And you HTML should be like the following:

```
<div class="search" onmouseover="altimage()" onmouseout="normimage()" style="width:30px;z-index:4;">
                        <img src="homelogo.jpg" alt="Home" class="menu" style="width:30px;height:30px;" id="homeicon">
                    </div>
```

Hope it helps!

Thanks